# Overriding img height for responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a slight problem in trying to make my website responsive as well as laying out images nicely with packery.

```
<div id="content"> // <- width of this determined through javascript
    <div class="imagecontainer">
        <img src="picture" width=500 height=700>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.imagecontainer{
   max-width:100%;
}
img{
    width:100%;
}
```

I've set the `max-width` at `100%` for my `imagecontainer`s so that they're never larger than the main `content` div. With the above code, however, the images inside get squashed horizontally as the `img`'s `width`, but not `height` is overruled by the `imagecontainer`'s `max-width`. The simple solution to this problem is of course to remove the `height` value from the `img`, but I've just painstakingly ADDED it so that [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) won't make a mockery of my layout when it's loading by placing posts on top of each other. Adding `height:auto` to the img css also ruins the layout (when it's loading, just to be clear).

The best solution I've come up with is to remove the `height` attribute from the image once it's loaded, but I was wondering if there's maybe an easier css-only solution, or a smarter way of doing it with js?

Comment: If the problem stems from the image's height during page load, consider using the `min-height` CSS property instead of the `height` attribute.

Comment: I get the exact same behavior with css `min-height` as with html `height` for the image, i.e. the images load where they should, but when the container is more narrow than the image, it gets squashed.

Comment: The issue is the layout does not seem to allow the image to have a fixed height or width or even a fixed minimum height or width. Consider setting a fixed minimum and removing it after load. You can do this simply by adding a class to the `content` element once its height is dynamically set by the script.

Comment: for what it's worth, I did it through javascript rather than css.